# Loop space of manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

**Question A:** The free loop space of a manifold is also a manifold?

**Question B:** The free loop space of an algebraic variety is also a algebraic variety ?

Are these questions asked or answered anywhere else? Any comments or references are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

A: Yes. See this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenient_vector_space#Application:_Manifolds_of_mappings_between_finite_dimensional_manifolds) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks,  Let now $X$ a compact manifold and $p: X^{S^1}\longrightarrow X$ a fibration that admits sections. Set $Sect(p)$ the non empty set of that sections, topologized with the open compact topology. My question is:  $Sect(p)$ inherits also a structure of manifold